What are the English dubbing credits for the 2008 movie "Ip Man"?
I was watching Ip Man (2008) on Peacock, and it seems like the original movie dialogue was in, I assume, Chinese. However, everything was dubbed in English.
I checked both Wikipedia and IMDb for the voice acting credits, but neither website lists this information.
Do voice-dubbing actors not receive credit for their work in movies? What are the English dubbing credits for Ip Man?
